# POST requests return HTTP error 308 on repl.it

Tags: python, replit

I need to make a post request from a modem onto one of my REPLs

The post request works fine when sent from a sufficiently advanced device (with automatic redirects), however, low-level requests always get stopped due to HTTP 308 (permanent redirect) errors.

Is there any way to fix this on repl?

Comment: Why do you assume that replit needs fixing? You could make some tweaks in your post request in your modem and that could fix it....

Comment: Because the post request works for sites not hosted on repl, but it seems that repl redirects to a specific repl when a request is sent instead of sending it directly or something of that nature